# ¿Optimizar varias consultas en un mismo SELECT SQL(MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo estas tabla1:

**view_conv_desp_trasv**

Con los siguientes campos.

1. referencia
2. conversion

y funciona asi:
ambos campos esta relacionados a una segunda tabla y hacen referencia al mismo campo.

por ejemplo:
referencia:9999
conversion:8888

aqui estoy diciendo que el codigo 8888 esta haciendo referencia al 9999 y ese codigo 9999 lo tengo que buscar en la segunda tabla para extraer datos.

tabla2:

**view_produccion_piku:**

aqui guardo estos campos:

1. cod_producto
2. fecha_produccion
3. hora_produccion
4. lote_piku

cod_producto es el campo que esta relacionado con referencia y conversion de la tabla1.

ahora un ejemplo para que se entienda mejor:
entran estos datos:

codigo conversion=8712

lote: 211105

ahi debo buscar cual es la referencia de ese codigo conversion, ese dati se ecuentra en la tabla1.

```
SELECT referencia from conversion WHERE conversion=8712;
```

referencia seria igual a=8888.

ya se cual es la referencia del codigo que esta entrando.

ahora debo extraer primer hora registrada y fecha de ese codigo referencia en la segunda tabla teniendo encuenta el lote que entro y que la hora min sea mayor a 6 am ('06:00:00').

```
    SELECT hora, fecha FROM view_produccion_piku  WHERE lote=211105 and 
cod_producto=8888 AND
hora=(select min(hora) from view_produccion_piku) AND
        view_produccion_piku.hora_produccion>'06:00:00';
```

esta me daria como resultado la primer hora y fecha de ese lote y ese codigo referencia que corresponde al codigo conversion.

Tengo la siguiente sql que hace todo en una sola consulta.
La consulta me funciona bien, pero quiero saber si no hay una mejor forma de optimizarlo.

```
 SELECT hora_produccion, fecha_produccion FROM view_produccion_piku WHERE
        view_produccion_piku.cod_producto=(SELECT referencia from view_conv_desp_trasv WHERE conversion=8712) AND
        view_produccion_piku.lote_piku=211105 AND 
        view_produccion_piku.hora_produccion=(SELECT min(view_produccion_piku.hora_produccion) FROM view_produccion_piku 
        WHERE view_produccion_piku.cod_producto=(SELECT referencia from view_conv_desp_trasv WHERE conversion=8712) AND
        view_produccion_piku.hora_produccion>'06:00:00' AND view_produccion_piku.lote_piku=211105);
```

Comment: Sugiero que de entrada enuncies tu problema: *quiero hacer tal cosa de tal modo* y luego explicas todo lo que quieras del contexto. Hice una primera lectura de tu pregunta y no queda claro cuál es el problema exactamente.

Comment: de entrada estoy mostrando una consulta SELECT, y quiero saber si la puedo optimizar o si asi esta bien. como puede ver en algunos WHERE tengo otras consultas select

Comment: para que tu consulta sea mas legible utiliza alias para las tablas como por ejemplo `SELECT hora_produccion, fecha_produccion FROM view_produccion_piku AS vpp WHERE
vpp.cod_producto=(SELECT referencia from view_conv_desp_trasv WHERE conversion=8712) AND
vpp.lote_piku=211105 AND 
vpp.hora_produccion=(SELECT min(vpp2.hora_produccion) FROM view_produccion_piku AS vpp2
WHERE vpp2.cod_producto=(SELECT referencia from view_conv_desp_trasv...`

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y completa la pregunta, explicando de entrada cual es el problema y el contexto. Cuando veo una pregunta dónde lo primero que te sueltan es el código pienso que muchos programadores son esclavos del código. El código es algo para resolver un problema, por eso lo más importante es entender bien ese problema. Cuando lo entiendes bien, ves más claro para resolverlo. Y si no puedes resolverlo, aquí te ayudaremos a hacerlo, pero de poco sirve ver un código sin que expliques el problema y el contexto.

Comment: ya estoy viendo varias cosas que podrías hacer con tantas subconsultas no te parecería mas optimo utilizar inner join admas se ejecutan mas rapido

Comment: @junior intente armar la consulta con join pero la verda me perdi. y me resulto mas facil hacer consultas en los where.  y me perdi sobre todo porque primero debo extraer el codigo referencia de ahi parte la consultas a la segunda tabla.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya la actualice no se si esta clara del todo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mueve las subsconsultas del `WHERE` al `FROM`:

```
SELECT hora_produccion
     , fecha_produccion 
  FROM view_produccion_piku pp
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT referencia 
                   FROM view_conv_desp_trasv 
                   WHERE conversion = 8712
               ) r
      ON r.referencia = pp.cod_producto
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT pp2.cod_producto
                      , min(pp2.hora_produccion) hora_produccion  
                   FROM view_produccion_piku pp2
                   WHERE pp2.hora_produccion > '06:00:00' 
                     AND pp2.lote_piku = 211105
                   GROUP BY pp2.cod_producto
               ) ppmin
      ON ppmin.cod_producto = pp.cod_producto
  WHERE pp.lote_piku = 211105 
    AND pp.hora_produccion = ppmin.hora_produccion
```

Comment: hola, gracias por tu respuesta podrias explicar lo que esta haciendo, gracias.

Comment: @CRIS19N: No podría explicarlo mejor que tú, es tu código, pero en otro lugar.

Comment: jajara me referia a los paso, ya lo entendi gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Los joins son mas óptimos que las subconsultas y los alias hacen que el codigo sea mas legible podrías cambiar la consulta por:

```
 SELECT pp.fecha_produccion, min(pp.hora_produccion) FROM view_produccion_piku AS pp
INNER JOIN view_conv_desp_trasv as cdt ON pp.cod_producto=cdt.referencia AND cdt.conversion=8712 WHERE pp.lote_piku=211105 AND  pp.hora_produccion>'06:00:00';
```

como necesitas obtener el min hora_produccion deberías pedirlo como salida todas las demás salidas se descartaran

Comment: ya los arregle @Sal